# xslt: trying to use value of align somewhere else

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I am trying to write an `If` or `when` statement that will check for the value of the `align` attribute of a table cell and will use that somewhere else.

Sample code:

Right now I have it written as

`<xsl:when test="../../../@align='left'"><th align="left"><xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</th></xsl:when>`

and I do this for "Left", "Center" and "Right" but I'd like to have something that will take care of whatever the value is and write that value. Sort of

`<xsl:when test="../../../@align='*'"><th align="*"><xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</th></xsl:when>`

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
<th align="{../../../@align}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</th>
```

(the `{...}` notation is called an *attribute value template*). If that ancestor element doesn't have an `align` attribut then you'll get `align=""` in the output. If that is a problem you could do

```
<th>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../../../@align"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</th>
```

This will create `<th align="....">` if the `align` attribute you're searching for in the input exists, but just `<th>` if it doesn't.